# how can i show the k value of 2 different parities in stocastik rsi

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

how can i show the k value of 2 different parities in stocastik rsi. If you have an example, can you help? For example, I want to see the k value of btcusdt parity in ethusdt parity, but no matter what parity I look at, btcusdt will be constant, I must see it constantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `request.security()` function to request data from different pairs.

Here is how you can do that:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
smoothK = input.int(3, "K", minval=1)
smoothD = input.int(3, "D", minval=1)
lengthRSI = input.int(14, "RSI Length", minval=1)
lengthStoch = input.int(14, "Stochastic Length", minval=1)
src = input(close, title="RSI Source")
_rsi = ta.rsi(src, lengthRSI)

rsi1 = request.security("BINANCE:BTCUSDT", timeframe.period, _rsi)

k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(rsi1, rsi1, rsi1, lengthStoch), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, smoothD)
plot(k)
```

[image]